# Uncaught Exception Flow error when run node migrationstatus

Tags: neoscms, flow-framework

I want to list all the available nodes that are not migrated yet. But when I run the command node:migrationstatus, the output displays the list of available migrations but also displays an error like this:

> Uncaught Exception: TYPO3\Flow\Error\Exception
>       Message
>       Warning: vsprintf(): Too few arguments in
>       /var/www/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Cli_ConsoleOutput.php
>       line 82